# Python adding to Pandas dataframe replaces info

Tags: python, pandas

I am scanning a directory of text files and adding them to a Pandas dataframe:

```
text_path = "/home/tdun0002/stash/cloud_scripts/aws_scripts/output_files/memory_stats/text/"
filelist = os.listdir(text_path)
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filelist:
    my_file = text_path + filename
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(my_file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
        final_df = final_df.append(df)
pd.options.display.max_rows
print(f"\n***Full Data Frame: {df}\n***")
```

Each file in the directory holds the memory of a server:

```
bastion001-memory.txt             
permissions001-memory.txt        
haproxy001-memory.txt
```

The contents of the files look something like this:

`cat haproxy001-memory.txt
7706172`

On each pass of adding the file, it reports this:

```
Data Frame: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [7706172]
Index: []
```

And when I print out the full data frame it only has the last entry:

```
***Full Data Frame:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [7706172]
Index: []
***
```

Why is it reporting that the dataframe is empty? Why is it only showing the last file that was input? I think I may need to append the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

- You need to provide `header=None` in `pd.read_csv` command to consider the value in text file as data. This is because by default, pandas assumes the first row to be header.
- Since you are reading multiple files, you need to append each dataframe into another. Currently you are overwriting df on each iteration.

Code should be like:

```
text_path = "/home/tdun0002/stash/cloud_scripts/aws_scripts/output_files/memory_stats/text/"
filelist = os.listdir(text_path)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filelist:
    my_file = text_path + filename
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(my_file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
        final_df = final_df.append(df)
        print(f"Data Frame: {df}")
pd.options.display.max_rows
print(f"\n***Full Data Frame: {df}\n***")
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. Each text file is being added to the DF now. But the Full Dataframe only shows this after making your changes: `Adding haproxy002-memory.txt to DF
Data Frame:          0
0  7706172`

So is all the data being added? Or is it still replacing the data each iteration?

Comment: After running your code, check the output of `print(final_df)`. It should give you the complete dataframe.

Comment: I've updated the OP to show the changes that I made, so it would be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks! That works. But now the data in the DF looks like this:

`0  7706172
0  7648524
0  7706172`
It looks like it's adding a column that has all zeros in it at the first column. Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: Can you please share your expected output in the question?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the delay. My Internet was out all day. The expected output should be, instead of `0 7706172` it should just have `7706172`. That's the amount of memory each instance has. It seems to be adding a `0` and a space before each memory count.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just did that. Any idea why it's adding a `0` and a space before the data I want on every row?